# customizing bootstrap form-control on select option

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, html-input, form-control

I'm using bootstrap's form-control class to keep a consistent style between my form input and those that requires a select option. However using bootstrap's form-control on select elements gives it the ugly drop-down button in firefox.[image]

What I'd like to achieve is this

[image]

However looking through the css part I have no way of identifying which part it is that I should override as there does not seem to be a css specifying the drop-down arrow's decoration.

This is how the current code looks like

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="industry" class="">Industry :</label>
    <select name="industry" class="form-control">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Industry</option>
        <option value="financial-service">Financial Services</option>
        <option value="healthcare-lifescience">Healthcare & Life Science</option>
        <option value="communications">Communications</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement Chosen(jQuery plugin for select) in it. It has lots of features on it and also you can design it easily.

Link: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

In your code :

```
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css"
  />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="industry" class="">Industry :</label>
    <select name="industry" id="industry" class="form-control chosen-select">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select Industry</option>
      <option value="financial-service">Financial Services</option>
      <option value="healthcare-lifescience">Healthcare & Life Science</option>
      <option value="communications">Communications</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <script>
    $("#industry").chosen();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Look up the custom-select class for bootstrap, as it makes it easier for you to style the select element as you need to.

A caveat is however, that support for styling the select/options is fairly limited. If you want full control, you would need to use a third-party package to covert the select to a custom html/javascript based select.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `-moz-appearance` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance) and set it to `none`.

By default, browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, ... apply a style to inputs, selects, dropdowns, etc. Using appearance allows you to remove this default style and apply your own using pseudo elements (already done in Bootstrap in your specific case).

Comment: How can i have the options display as a tray rather than the normal popup ?

Answer (score 0):

**Check My Pen for you. It is 100% working in chrome, firefox, edge and safari**

[check this codepen](https://codepen.io/awesomeSri/pen/pmZPyK)

```css
select.customDropdown::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}

select.customDropdown {
    outline : none;
    overflow : hidden;
    text-indent : 0.01px;
    text-overflow : '';
    
    background : url("https://img.icons8.com/material/24/000000/sort-down.png") no-repeat right #fff;

    -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
        -ms-appearance: none;
         -o-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="jumbotron container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="industry" class="">Industry :</label>
    <select name="industry" class="form-control customDropdown">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Industry</option>
        <option value="financial-service">Financial Services</option>
        <option value="healthcare-lifescience">Healthcare & Life Science</option>
        <option value="communications">Communications</option>
    </select>
</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```